# Powershell, how to update several dns records

Tags: powershell, dns

I have the following script, but am getting an error -

Script -

```
$CNAMES = Get-Content "C:\Temp\alias.txt"
$Query = "Select * from MicrosoftDNS_CNAMEType"
$Record = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\microsoftdns" -Query $Query -ComputerName 10.10.10.1 | Where-Object{$_.Ownername -match $CNAME}
Foreach($CNAME in $CNAMES)
{
  $Record.RecordData = "some.server.net"
  $Record.put()
}
```

Error -

```
Property 'RecordData' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\temp\DNSUpdateCNAMETarget_02.ps1:7 char:9
+ $Record. <<<< RecordData = "some.server.net"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'put'.
At C:\temp\DNSUpdateCNAMETarget_02.ps1:8 char:12
+ $Record.put <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (put:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I didn't try (cause i don't have a MS-DNS at hand right now) but i'd suspect that you need</strike>

```
$Record.PSBase.Put()
```

to make it work.

**EDIT:**

As it looks ***$Record*** holds an array of ***System.Object*** so will have to cast it a suitable type to access ***.RecordData*** and ***.Put()***

Your script queries for records of type [MicrossoftDNS_CNAMEType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682196%28VS.85%29.aspx) which only support [CreateInstanceFromPropertyData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682668%28VS.85%29.aspx).

I would try sending you $Record to Get-Member

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\microsoftdns" -Query $Query -ComputerName 10.10.10.1 | Get-Member
```

to find out, what you are dealing with.